# Kivy приложение вылетает на логотипе

Tags: python, kivy

Пишу приложение на Kivy, с использованием KivyMD и возникла проблемка. Пока я работал с ним на ПК, оно работало корректно, но стоило мне его скомпилить под андроид, как оно отказалось там запускаться. После надписи Loading... оно просто вылетает без всякой ошибки.
Я полез в logcat смотреть, в чем дело, и в итоге имею две возможные причины не запуска приложения.

Первое, что я нашел, так это ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'
Странно, ведь другие приложения, работающие на KivyMD у меня запускаются нормально.

Второе, что я нашел, это большой лог с некой ошибкой, прикрепляю его сюда:

```
get life cycle exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.AsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
 at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(Unknown Source:29)
 at android.app.Activity.onResume(Unknown Source:52)
 at org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.onResume(SDLActivity.java:313)
 at org.kivy.android.PythonActivity.onResume(PythonActivity.java:514)
 at org.kivy.android.PythonActivity$UnpackFilesTask.onPostExecute(PythonActivity.java:199)
 at org.kivy.android.PythonActivity$UnpackFilesTask.onPostExecute(PythonActivity.java:99)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(Unknown Source:10)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source:28)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:19)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:242)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:98)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:275)
```

Не пойму в чем здесь дело, прошу помощи. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Киви вообще глючное. Не рекомендую. А почему не работает, не знаю, без кода точно не догадаться.

Comment: Вот код, так уж и быть: https://github.com/eigo228/Glebculator

Comment: 1. 404 2. в смысле так уж и быть,  мне может вообще не интерестно с ним париться ;)

Comment: Да без обид, ничего такого. Я открыл доступ

Comment: Что интересно, запуская через PyDroid у меня все работает. А так крашится

Comment: Запустил твою прогой на убунте  у ся, просто пустое окно... т-т-ак все и должно быть?

Comment: Все :) проблему решил тем, что прописал в buildozer.spec в requirements еще kivymd. Все заработало. Насчет пустого окна, там еще файл calc.kv его надо в одну папку с main.py сунуть чтоб работало